# Query for inserting into temporary table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table absences that has the following fields

> id , utilisateurs_id, date_debut , date_fin,type, `statut

I will explain my problem based on example :

```
        ----------------+------------------+------------------+---------------------
       |id              |  utilisateurs_id |date_debut        | date_fin           |
        ----------------+------------------+------------------+---------------------
       |     15         |          12      |2012-01-20        |2012-01-25          |
        ----------------+------------------+------------------+---------------------
       |     20         |          12      |2012-01-27        |2012-01-29          |
        ----------------+------------------+------------------+---------------------
       |     23         |          17      |2012-01-20        |2012-01-2           |
        ----------------+------------------+------------------+---------------------
       |     27         |          12      |2012-04-10        |2012-04-12          |
        ----------------+------------------+------------------+---------------------
```

I would like to find a way to fill a temporary table tempabsence which have the same fields as absences and if there is redundancy for id calculate the difference between enddate and startdate and if this difference is less than 3 , enddate get the value of startdate else insert this column in tempabsences

```
    ----------------+------------------+------------------+---------------------
   |id              |  utilisateurs_id |date_debut        | date_fin           |
    ----------------+------------------+------------------+---------------------
   |     15         |          12      |2012-01-20        |2012-01-29          |
    ----------------+------------------+------------------+---------------------
   |     23         |          17      |2012-01-20        |2012-01-2           |
    ----------------+------------------+------------------+---------------------
   |     27         |          12      |2012-04-10        |2012-04-12          |
    ----------------+------------------+------------------+---------------------
```

I tried to implement it but the script does not return the result that I want .

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempabsences  LIKE absences;


    INSERT INTO tempabsences(id ,utilisateurs_id,date_debut,tempabsences.date_fin,type,statut)
    SELECT absences.utilisateurs_id ,absences.utilisateurs_id,absences.date_debut,absences.date_fin,absences.type,absences.statut
    FROM absences 
    ORDER BY absences.date_debut ASC,absences.date_fin ASC, absences.utilisateurs_id ASC
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE tempabsences.date_fin=IF(abs(DATEDIFF(tempabsences.date_fin,absences.date_debut)<3) and (tempabsences.utilisateurs_id=absences.utilisateurs_id),tempabsences.date_fin,absences.date_fin),
                tempabsences.utilisateurs_id= IF(abs(DATEDIFF(tempabsences.date_fin,absences.date_debut)<3)and (tempabsences.utilisateurs_id=absences.utilisateurs_id),tempabsences.utilisateurs_id,absences.utilisateurs_id),
                tempabsences.id=IF(abs(DATEDIFF(tempabsences.date_fin,absences.date_debut)<3)and (tempabsences.utilisateurs_id=absences.utilisateurs_id),tempabsences.id,(select tempabsences.id from absences ) )
    ;
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated .
Regards .

Comment: I have condition of the difference between dates that I didn't know how to handle it .

Comment: My apologies - comment removed

Comment: You use `ON DUPLICATE KEY` but you didn't specify what was the key in your table. I assume (id , utilisateurs_id)?

Comment: @Kleskowy the primary key for both tables absences and tempabsences is id .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it must be something like

```
BEGIN
  FOR rec_ IN (
                SELECT absences.utilisateurs_id ,absences.utilisateurs_id,absences.date_debut,absences.date_fin,absences.type,absences.statut
                FROM absences 
                ORDER BY absences.date_debut ASC,absences.date_fin ASC, absences.utilisateurs_id ASC
                )

     BEGIN           
        INSERT INTO tempabsences(rec_.id ,rec_.utilisateurs_id,rec_.date_debut,rec_.tempabsences.rec_.date_fin,rec_.type,rec_.statut);
     EXCEPTION
       WHEN dup_val_on_index THEN

        for rec2_ in (SELECT * FROM tempabsences WHERE id = rec_.utilisateurs_id) loop

          if rec2_.date_fin  - rec2_.date_debut < 3 then

              update absences
                 set date_fin = date_debut
                where utilisateurs_id = rec_.utilisateurs_id;

          else
             ----- else statement here
          end if;
        end loop;

     END;

END;
```

Comment: @Calipo Could you explain me more please ? I didn't get very well the algorithm

Comment: As far as I could understand from the question he wants to directly insert the absences value to the temp table. I made a row by row insert with for loop to be able to get errors by row. Received the exception with a handler (I am using Oracle PLSQL syntax). when there is a duplicate value it goes to the handler and then goes to the if block